# Sortable Shapes

Tags: c#, object-oriented, programming-challenge

Description:

Although shapes can be very different by nature, they can be sorted by the size of their area.

Create different shapes that can be part of a sortable list. The sort order is based on the size of their respective areas:

The area of a **Square** is the square of its *side*
The area of a **Rectangle** is *width* multiplied by height
The area of a **Triangle** is base multiplied by height divided by 2
The area of a **Circle** is the square of its radius multiplied by π
The area of a **CustomShape** is given

The default sort order of a list of shapes is ascending on area size:

```
var side = 1.1234D;
var radius = 1.1234D;
var base = 5D;
var height = 2D;

var shapes = new List<Shape>{ new Square(side),
                        new Circle(radius),
                        new Triangle(base, height) };
shapes.Sort();
```

- Use the correct π constant for your circle area calculations:

  `System.Math.PI`

And you only have tests cases to base your code on.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    [TestFixture]
    public class ShapesTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void ShapesAreSortableOnArea()
        {
            // Arrange
            double width, height, triangleBase, side, radius, area;
            Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);

            var expected = new List<Shape>();

            area = 1.1234;
            expected.Add(new CustomShape(area));

            side = 1.1234;
            expected.Add(new Square(side));

            radius = 1.1234;
            expected.Add(new Circle(radius));

            triangleBase = 5;
            height = 2;
            expected.Add(new Triangle(triangleBase, height));

            height = 3;
            triangleBase = 4;
            expected.Add(new Triangle(triangleBase, height));

            width = 4;
            expected.Add(new Rectangle(width, height));

            area = 16.1;
            expected.Add(new CustomShape(area));

            var actual = expected.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToList(); 

            // Act
            actual.Sort();

            // Assert
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                Assert.AreEqual(expected[i], actual[i]);
        }
    }
```

My answer below was correct I would like it reviewed and if possible      refactored or Improved this was a question I got on Codewars.com and my solution passed all tests on the site.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Shape : IComparable<Shape>
        {
            public double Area { get; set; }

            public int CompareTo(Shape other)
            {
                return this.Area.CompareTo(other.Area);
            }

        }

        public class Square : Shape 
        {
            public Square(double side)
            {
                Area = side * side;
            }
        }

        public class CustomShape : Shape
        {
            public CustomShape(double area)
            {
                Area = area;
            }
        }

        public class Circle : Shape 
        {
            public Circle(double radius)
            {
                Area = (radius * radius) * Math.PI;
            }
        }

        public class Rectangle : Shape
        {
            public Rectangle(double width , double height)
            {
                Area = width * height;
            }
        }

        public class Triangle : Shape
        {
            public Triangle(double Base, double height)
            {
                Area = (Base * height) / 2;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This looks like a [kata from Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/sortable-shapes). Please make sure to show what code is yours and what code is from the site.

Comment: This question is from Codewars but @Zeta but this is ALL MY CODE...

Comment: No. The test case isn't. Neither is the description. Keep in mind that by posting your question you licence it under CC-BY-SA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main thing I see in your solution, is that your derived classes, would need quite a bit of re-factoring if you needed them in a more general sense.  I think having each shape with its own parameters and its own getter for the Area property, is much more adaptable:

```
public class Square : Shape
{
    public double side { get; set; }
    public double Area
    {
        get { return side * side; }
    }
    public Square(double side)
    {
        this.side = side;
    }
}
```

Comment: The principle is good, but to nitpick coding conventions: in C# the property should have an initial capital: `Side`.

Answer (score 3):

Your hierarchy presumes that every descendant class will call `Area` setter. That's wishful thinking. :) You will get away with it in this small exercise, but you wont in more complex projects.

You should make `Area` abstract.

```
public abstract class ShapeBase : IComparable<Shape>
{
    public abstract double Area { get; }

    public int CompareTo(Shape other)
    {
        return this.Area.CompareTo(other.Area);
    }
}
```

This will enforce every descendant to override it. Note, that there is no public setter. It should not be possible to execute this code:

```
new Circle(1) { Area = 200000 };
```

---

Also, you should normally override equality methods if you implement `IComparable<T>`. If `CompareTo` returns `0`, `Equals` should not return `false`.

Comment: does that mean I have to override all of equality then

Comment: @GringoJaimes, you have to override `Object.Equals()`, `IEquatable<T>.Equals()` and `Object.GetHashCode()`. Alternatively you can implement stand-alone `IComparer<T>`. Then you don't have to do all that.